# ffmpeg arguments used for converting to mp4

Tags: audio, video

I have been suggested two different ffmpeg commands for converting an mkv file to an mp4 while just re-encoding the audio (to aac) and leaving the video portion as is. Here are the two commands:

1. `ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i source.mkv -vcodec copy -c:a aac -strict -2 -ab 160k -ac 2 -ar 48k target.mp4`
2. `ffmpeg -i source.mkv -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 384k -strict -2 target.mp4`

Could someone please explain the difference? OK, more precisely, I am curious about the things the first command does in addition to what the second one does. Is it necessary to use a **-log level panic** argument? What happens if it's omitted?

I understand the second command thoroughly. But the additional arguments in the first one are confusing me and I didn't find much help in the [ffmpeg documentation](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide#ShouldIuseAAC-LCorAAC-HE) either. In particular, I want to understand what the **-ac**, **-ar**, and **-ab** arguments accomplish and why are they not used in the second command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffmpeg duplicates syntax. Except for the values used, and that the first command set the sampling rate instead of using the default, the commands are effectively the same:

```
 -loglevel panic  - merely makes ffmpeg less noisy in the shell
 -vcodec copy     = -c:v copy
 -acodec copy     = -c:a copy   # unlisted in the command, but listing here to show there is consistency
 -ab              = -b:a
```

Note: The other answer info is correct.

There is a [guide](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) online; it lists what every possible argument means.

Answer (score 2):

The three flags ask for a 2 channel, 48000 Hz sampled, 160k bit rate encoded audio track.

The flags that can be passed to `ffmpeg` are listed in the [ffmpeg manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg). Manual pages tend to be terse but informative:

## ac

```
-ac channels
```

Set the number of audio channels (default = 1).

## ar

```
-ar freq
```

Set the audio sampling frequency (default = 44100 Hz).

## ab

```
-ab bitrate
```

Set the audio bitrate in bit/s (default = 64k).

Comment: if -ab sets the bitrate, isn't it the same as -b:a?

Comment: Why not try both and compare the output? It certainly looks possible to double set values with a tool as sophisticated and capable as `ffmpeg`.